# C++ template black magic

Tags: c++, templates

This needs only work in g++.

I want a function

```
template<typename T> std::string magic();
```

such that:

```
Class Foo{}; magic<Foo>(); // returns "Foo";
Class Bar{}; magic<Bar>(); // returns "Bar";
```

I don't want this to be done via specialization (i.e. having to define magic for each type. I'm hoping to pull some macro/template black magic here. Anyone know how?)

Thanks!

Comment: Now what part of that is necessary and what part are you just writing because you think it's needed.  Is class Foo important?  Give us a more realistic use case.

Comment: Its a fairly obvious requirement for some kind of simple static reflection mechanism, that doesn't bring in the full gamut of RTTI.

Comment: I want to have a function that I can pass it any type, and it'll return for me the name of the type.

Comment: In *C++* probably you are looking template black magic. If so, [Modern C++ Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design) will be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `typeid(Foo).name()` for a start. Parse as you see fit; will be implementation-dependent (but simply getting a string back is portable).

Comment: Parse as you see fit, eg: `char *n = typeid(Foo).name(); while ( *n && *n < 'A' ) ++ n;`

Answer (score 13):

To convert a type (or other identifer) into a string you need a macro, but a macro can not check if it's parameter is a valid type. To add type checking a template function can be added to the macro:

```
template<typename T>
std::string magic_impl(const char *name) { return name; }

#define more_magic(a) magic_impl<a>(#a)
#define magic(a) more_magic(a)
```

Here `magic(int)` gives the string `"int"` while `magic(Foo)` gives a *"‘Foo’ was not declared"* error if there is no such class.

Comment: Of all the answers given here I like this answer the best because a) It does typechecking b) The result is the class name and not any mangled form which may be compiler dependent.

Comment: more_magic exists just to check that a type named "a" is declared and is in scope. Without that I could call magic(%%%%) and get the call to succeed even though %%%% couldn't have been a legal name for a type.

Answer (score 4):

The stringizing operator on macros may be what you're looking for:

```
#define MAGICCLASSNAME(str) std::string magic(#str)
class Foo{}; MAGICCLASSNAME(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;
class Foo{}; 
class Bar{};

template<typename T> 
inline std::string magic(const T& obj)
{
 return typeid(obj).name();
}

int main()
{
 Foo a;
 cout << magic<Foo>(a); // returns "Foo";
}
```

I tested this with g++ and works well.

Also I got it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024648/retrieving-a-c-class-name-programatically/1024655#1024655) SO answer.