# How do i find the struct name from the instance?

Tags: c++

I have user-defined struct

```
template < class T >
struct OutputValue : public OutputBase 
{
 ..
}
```

and

```
template < class T >
struct OutputValueRange : public OutputValue<T> 
{
 ..
}
```

Now I have declared two member variables

```
OutputValue<double>             m_dStimulatedAudioLatency;
OutputValueRange<double>        m_dDecodeAudioLatency;
```

I need to get the struct name of the member variables.Expected output is

```
m_dStimulatedAudioLatency.structname() = OutputValue
m_dDecodeAudioLatency.structname() = OutputValueRange
```

I tried doing-

[How can I get the class name from a C++ object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649278/how-can-i-get-the-class-name-from-a-c-object)

but I got something like this as output

```
   class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char>>
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: your link points to a question. Did you wanted to link the answer? Anyhow your code should be included in your question

Comment: There is no reflection (yet) in C++, that data is unavailable unless you provide it by yourself one way or another

Comment: I tried the solution in that link, but didn't get

Comment: I didn't get u @Slava

Comment: Note that [`std::type_info::name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) returns the name of a type *in some form*. There is no restrictions or guaranties, other than it's a null terminated character string. And that's the only portable solution, as far as I know. Otherwise, you need to come up with your own scheme.

Comment: there is no "the solution" in your link, but it points to a question with several simliar albeit different answers

Comment: Which part you do not get? What is reflection? Read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)

Comment: What is `...structname() = value;` supposed to do?

Comment: I somehow need to get the name of the struct, so"...structname() = value;"is my expected output

Comment: what type is `structname()` output?

Comment: How do you plan to use said type name? To print it or to declare new variables?

Comment: Why do you need the type name during run-time?

Comment: What code are you running to get the output that you say you are getting when you try the method you linked? Because that looks like it's the correct output for if you were getting the type of a std::string instead of one of your own classes...