# How to find out the child class name inside a method of a parent class if the method of the parent class was called by an object of the child class

Tags: c++, oop

I need to know how this is done in C++ programming

c++ programming: How to find out the child class name inside a method of a parent class if the method of the parent class was called by an object of the child class

Comment: Sounds like a job for virtual functions.

Comment: What is the actual underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need the "class name"? What is the "class name" supposed to be used for?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] to illustrate the question.  The terminology is a little unclear and an example of what you want would help a lot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean getting a string that stores the derived class' name?

Take a look at
[How can I get the class name from a C++ object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649278/how-can-i-get-the-class-name-from-a-c-object)

You can use the "typeid" approach in tandem with virtual functions to achieve the goal of printing the derived class' name by calling the method from the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to know the exact child class from which the non-virtual parent method is called. For example:

```
class B
{
public:
    void Foo()
    {
        // Need the child class from which Foo() is called (id or name string)
    }
    static void SFoo()
    {
        // Get the child class from which SFoo() is called (id or name string)
    }
}

class D1: public B
{
// D1 members
}

class D2: public B
{
// D2 members
}

main()
{
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;

    d1.Foo();
    d2.Foo();
    D1::SFoo();
    D2::SFoo();
}
```