# C++ equivalent of Java's this.getClass().getSimpleName();

Tags: java, c++, class, rtti, names

In Java, if I want to use the object class' name I can write:

```
String myString = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

What's the C++ equivalent of this? That is, how can I get a string with the name of the class of `*this`?

Comment: Seems like [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024648/retrieving-a-c-class-name-programatically)

Answer (score 5):

There is no equivalent in standard C++.  The closest you'll get is `typeid(*this).name()`, but there's no guarantee about what the "name" will look like - the result is implementation-defined.  It will basically be whatever your compiler decided to put there, which may or may not correspond to the class's name in the source code. See [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) for more information.

If you want to know the name of a class whose code you can change, you could write a function that returns a readable name.  But otherwise, you're basically stuck with whatever the code above returns.

Comment: @einpoklum: `name()` returns an *implementation-defined* name.  Which basically means it could be anything; it need not even be human-readable or unique.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Where A is class

```
typeid(A).name()
```

Comment: In gcc the result of typeid().name() is the mangled class name.

Comment: @JonnyHenly typename instead

Comment: No, this is not what I asked. I don't want to pass a class. I want to get the name of the class of `*this`. i.e. I want subtype polymorphism here.

Comment: You are working on 'this' that means you are already working inside class then why now write a member function which returns you class name string or char*? That's because we don't have any direct way in C++!

Answer (score 0):

We can Create our own Function For that,

```
class ClassName
{ 
     static std::string const className() 
     { 
         return "ClassName"; 
     }
};
std::string const name = ClassName::className();
```

The `QObject->metaObject()` method is valid for `Qt` except the `QGraphicsItem` based classes that not inherit from `QObject`.

Comment: Of course the whole point is to avoid the need to implement this method for every class...

Comment: For C++11 you might be able to make use of the `__func__` macro inside the class constructor to save the class name somewhere specific so that your generic className() member function will work. In the constructor  `__func__` obviously will expand to the name of the class